# MySQL dynamic loop through table and delete rows based on condition

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to loop through tables and delete rows based on condition
I can get all the tables like this:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'mytables'
```

Is it possible to loop through all them and perform query similar to this:

```
DELETE FROM table where NOW() > ColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the statement that selects the tables and for every table_name execute:

```
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT('DELETE FROM',table_name,' WHERE NOW() > ColumnName');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: i am getting this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT('DELETE FROM',table_name,' WHERE NOW() > ColumnName')' at line 3